# Не могу записать нужное мне значение переменной в SQLite3

Tags: python, sqlite3

Сегодня только начал изучать SQlite3, поэтому не обессудьте. Извиняюсь, если дубликат.
Есть у меня такой фрагмент кода:

```
gtavgen_tokens = sqlite3.connect('gtavgen_tokens')
sql = gtavgen_tokens.cursor()
sql.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS gtavtokens (
    gtavtokens TEXT
)""")
payid = ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range (15))
gtavgen_tokens.execute(f"INSERT INTO `gtavtokens` VALUES ('{payid}')")
gtavgen_tokens.commit()
print(gtavgen_tokens)
```

После запуска кода получаю ошибку:

```
gtavgen_tokens.execute(f"INSERT INTO gtavtokens VALUES ('{payid}')")
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. The object was created in thread id 10216 and this is thread id 10320.
```

Что можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ну в первую очередь, понять что запросы к бд делать через фун-ю

```
def insert_payid(payid: str):
    gtavgen_tokens = sqlite3.connect('gtavgen_tokens')
    sql = gtavgen_tokens.cursor()
    sql.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS gtavtokens (gtavtokens TEXT)""")
    payid = ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range (15))
    gtavgen_tokens.execute(f"INSERT INTO gtavtokens (gtavtokens,) VALUES ('{payid}',)")
    gtavgen_tokens.commit()
    gtavgen_tokens.close()
```

Comment: и вообще, лучше сделать себе функцию для обработки запросов к базе